# Is a right circular cylinder a Lipschitz domain?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I am aware of this post [Is a cylinder a Lipschitz domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513565/is-a-cylinder-a-lipschitz-domain), but it has no definitive answer apparently. As far as the definition goes, I don't think I have a good geometrical understanding of a Lipschitz domain, so I was hoping if someone could answer this question. Is a right circular cylinder a Lipschitz domain?

Comment: I should have commented on this earlier than this. The answer is yes, it is a Lipschitz domain.